# Strange shiny reflection on terrain

Tags: unity, shaders, terrain, unity-urp

So I'm trying to figure out, what's causing this strange reflection on my terrain.
I've tried almost everything to get rid of that shiny circle, but to no avail. It follows me wherever I go, so it's not static either. I'm using Realtime lighting at the moment.
I tried changing the Alpha Source on my grass texture to None, tried bringing to specular down, tried creating a different terrain material, regenerated the lightmap but nothing seems to work. (I'm using URP, Unity 2021.2.1f1)

The problem:
[image]

My settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought adding the normal map for the grass texture fixed the problem but it actually didn't, it just wasn't that apparent anymore. The terrain is still very reflective.

Answer (score 2):

What @Marc-Diprose said worked for me.
Follow these steps to remove the shiny blot:

1. Locate your texture in Unity's File Explorer.
2. Click on the texture that is giving you an issue.
3. In the Inspector the 4th option down is **Alpha Source**; use the drop down and select **From Gray Scale**.
4. Click **Apply**.

Scene should update the texture on the terrain and fix the lighting issue.

Before the fix:
[image: Before Fix]

After the fix:
[image: After Fix]

Answer (score 1):

On the texture import settings, make the Alpha 'From grayscale' and if that alone doesnt fix it, change the format to RGB 24 BIT to discard the alpha channel - the alpha channel is what causes the specularity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).